# Is there an another way to have the value of an expression in C# than selection statements

Tags: c#, if-statement

Edit : I have some of you confused, it's not a test more a POC or a little piece of code to understand how to do something.

I need to compare two values.

I tried by doing a POC of what I need to do, but I'm a bit confused.

My test for my POC look like this :

```
public bool ValueMethod()
{
    bool returnValue = false;
    var expectedValue = new List<string>()
    {
        "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"
    };
    var ValueTestTrue = "Value1";
    var ValueTestFalse = "Value4";
    if (expectedValue.Contains(ValueTestTrue) && !expectedValue.Contains(ValueTestFalse))
    {
         returnValue = true;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

How can I do this but without an `if` statement ?

I need to apply this on a bigger project but I want to understand how to do my POC first.

My real Project look something like this

```
public bool Load(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument)
{
    bool returnValue = false;
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = ExcelHelper.GetWorksheetFromSheetName(workbookPart, "Computer");
    if (worksheetPart != null)
    {
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetSata>();
        if (computerList.Contains(ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(WorkbookPart, sheetData, "A2")))
        {
            returnValue = true;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `return (expectedValue.Contains(ValueTestTrue) && !expectedValue.Contains(ValueTestFalse))` ?

Comment: If isn't evil? Can you rephrase your problem what you actually want. Just wanting to get rid of if statements is weird.

Comment: Writing the test this way in the first place is suspect. These are logically two separate tests of two separate values, so write them separately. The `expectedValue` list can be shared between them, in more than one way.

Comment: @Ralf I know that `if` isn't evil and if I was the only one to work on the project I would have done it hat way but since I'm in apprenticeship, my tutor doesn't want to do it with `if` statements.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev In the complete project I retrieve text from an excel sheet and compare it to specific word that I already have in a list. If the two words match then I can create an object but i need to do this without an if statement.

Comment: Can you write your example to be closer to what your actual method looks like? Atm. The problem is a bit unclear.

Comment: @tymtam I am going to edit  my post

Answer (score 0):

try using inline condition like here

```
public bool TestMethod()
    {
        var expectedValue = new List<string>()
        {
            "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"
        };
        var ValueTestTrue = "Value1";
        var ValueTestFalse = "Value4";
        bool returnValue  =  (expectedValue.Contains(ValueTestTrue) && !expectedValue.Contains(ValueTestFalse));
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: I think you forgot `!` in `&& expectedValue.Contains(ValueTestFalse)`

Answer (score 0):

The code in `Load` looks fine.

You can simplify it, and remove the `if`, but this is not that important.

```
public bool LoadAndCheckForComputer(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument)
{
    var workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    var worksheetPart = ExcelHelper.GetWorksheetFromSheetName(workbookPart, "Computer");
    
    if (worksheetPart == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetSata>();
    return computerList.Contains(ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(WorkbookPart, sheetData, "A2")))
}
```

*I don't know if Excel sheets always have the first child and if you have to check sheet data for `null`.*

---

For `valueMethod` you can apply the same pricinples:

```
public bool ValueMethod()
{
    var expectedValue = new List<string>()
    {
        "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"
    };
    var valueTestTrue = "Value1";
    var valueTestFalse = "Value4";

    return expectedValue.Contains(valueTestTrue) 
       && !expectedValue.Contains(ValueTestFalse))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get why would you need such a code. Looks like it's an artificial constraint for learning.

Then your function could look like:

```cs
public bool Load(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument)
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = ExcelHelper.GetWorksheetFromSheetName(workbookPart, "Computer");

    return worksheetPart != null 
        && worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetSata>() is SheetData sheetData
        && sheetData != null
        && computerList.Contains(ExcelHelper.GetCellValue(WorkbookPart, sheetData, "A2"))
}
```